# libcurl's default behavior for certificate pinning

Tags: c++, curl, https, ssl-certificate, libcurl

We are sending requests to a server using libcurl (7.51.0). We have a .pem file where we have a set of CA certificates that are being set via CURLOPT_CAINFO option.

```
curl_easy_setopt(mpCURL, CURLOPT_CAINFO,  "/usr/certs/certificates.pem");
```

Now, I would like to figure out whether the CA certificates present within the .pem are pinned or not. How do I achieve this?

Also, according to the answer in the question [Public key pinning in curl does not work without using certificates from the system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52114653/public-key-pinning-in-curl-does-not-work-without-using-certificates-from-the-sys), it seems like as long as the CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST options are left as defaults and a set of CA certificates are provided via CURLOPT_CAINFO, cURL library implements CA certificate pinning by default. Is that correct? Does that mean that libcurl pins all the certificates that are present in the .pem file?

Answer (score 1):

I confirmed that CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER's default value enables CA pinning by default. As a result, it uses the certificates mentioned in CAPATH for CA pinning.